# Reduce logs generated by SpringMVC application

Tags: spring-mvc, logging

I have a SpringMVC 3 application which uses Spring Security, AOP, HIbernate etc.

But when I run it in Tomcat or Jetty, it generates a huge amount of log.

How can I reduce this log?

I want a log level starting from `WARNING`.

Example of the log:

```
21:16:08.393 [qtp12506312-25] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionEventPublisher - Publishing event: org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessi onCreatedEvent[source=org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.HashedSess ion:db7nzoxke45es1k02gbug79d@6784961]
21:16:08.394 [qtp12506312-25] DEBUG o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache - DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/favicon.ico]
21:16:08.394 [qtp12506312-25] DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter - Calling Authentication entry point.
21:16:08.440 [qtp12506312-25] DEBUG o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy - Redirecting to 'http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/default;jsessionid=db7nzoxke45es1k02gbug79d'
21:16:08.441 [qtp12506312-25] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
21:16:08.441 [qtp12506312-25] DEBUG o.s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
21:16:08.518 [qtp12506312-26] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/default'; against '/loginform.jsp'
21:16:08.518 [qtp12506312-26] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/default'; against '/loginform2.jsp'
21:16:08.518 [qtp12506312-26] DEBUG o.s.s.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher - Checking match of request : '/default'; against '/default'
21:16:08.518 [qtp12506312-26] DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy - /default has an empty filter list
```

Comment: which is the logging framework used log4j / logback

Answer (score 1):

If you are using logback for logging then change the root logger's log lever to WARNING, you can find the logback.xml file in the classpath

Ex:

```
<root level="WARN">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
</root>
```

If you are using log4j, you can find the log4j.properties file in your classpath. Change the rootlogger level to WARNING again

```
log4j.rootLogger=WARNING , A1
```